# purpose of this loopcounter, confused

Tags: php

I'm a little confused regarding this code; loopcounter. can someone please clarify what it means please? I am new to this.

I'm a little confused regarding this code; loopcounter. can someone please clarify what it means please? I am new to this.

```
$loopCounter = 0;
                                        $highlight = true;
                                        while ($dbRow=mysqli_fetch_array($dbResult))
                                        {
                                            if($highlight == true)
                                            {
                                                echo '<tr class="alternateRowColor">';
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                echo '<tr>';
                                            }
                                            $highlight = !$highlight;                                           

                                            echo '<td>'. $dbRow['id'] .'</td>';
                                            echo '<td>'. $dbRow['first_name']. ' ' .$dbRow['last_name'].'</td>';
                                            echo ' <td>'. $dbRow['user_id'] .'</td>';   
                                            echo ' <td>'. $dbRow['amount'] .'</td>';
                                            echo ' <td>'. $dbRow['currency'] .'</td>';
                                            echo ' <td>'. $dbRow['type'] .'</td>';
                                            echo ' <td>'. $dbRow['description'] .'</td>';
                                            echo ' <td>'. $dbRow['submission'] .'</td>';
                                            echo ' <td>'. $dbRow['status'] .'</td>';

                                            $loopCounter++;
                                    ?>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo "all_ids[]" ?>" value="<?php echo $dbRow['id'] ?>"/></td>
                                    <?php                                       
                                            echo '<td><input type="radio" name="'.$dbRow['id'].'" value="A" checked="checked"></td>';
                                            echo '<td><input type="radio" name="'.$dbRow['id'].'" value="D"></td></tr>';

                                        }

                                    echo "</table>";
                                    ?>

                                    <p>
                                        <input type="submit" name="process" id="process" value="Process" class="button">
                                    </p>
                                </form>
```

Comment: Basically, if you print the value of `$loopCounter` , it shows how many number of rows your query returned.

Answer (score 0):

loopCounter serves no purpose in this code. It does keep track of the iterations, but this snippet does nothing with that.

Answer (score 0):

The variable name clearly defines what the purpose of the variable is intended to be.

However, if the variable isn't used for any other purpose other than what is shown, then it should be deleted since it doesn't have any impact.

Comment: $loopCounter++;
         ?>
          <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo "all_ids[]" ?>" value="<?php echo $dbRow['id'] ?>"/></td>
         <?php          
           echo '<td><input type="radio" name="'.$dbRow['id'].'" value="A" checked="checked"></td>';
           echo '<td><input type="radio" name="'.$dbRow['id'].'" value="D"></td></tr>';
          
          }

         echo "</table>";
         ?> this is also included

Comment: If you are not providing complete code, update your OP to include full, properly formatted code. Providing incomplete code doesn't help in getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid manual `mysqli_num_rows()` implementation. Counts rows in query result. Makes sense only if you use unbuffered queries.